# Wait termination of threads work before close a server after receiving SIGINT or SIGTERM (Posix thread in C)

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I'm developing a client / server in C using pthread.

It's a card game where `server` is the dealer between two `clients` that play.

I have this situation

**server.c**:

**main:**

- `int main (int argc, char * argv[])`

  using as a thread dispatcher for listening eventually entering connection on `accept`
- `pthread_create(&sig_thread, NULL, &thread_signal_handler, &server_Socket );`

  thread to catch signals (maskered conveniently) created inside *main* function
- `pthread_create(&tid[i++], NULL, &worker, (void*) arr_args)`

  every client is associated to a thread created (*tid* is the array of *thread* ID)
- `pthread_join(sig_thread, NULL)`

  to join thread for signals
- `pthread_join(tid[i], NULL)`

  to join thread created for every client connected.

**worker:**

- `void * worker(void * args)`

  do his job and terminated

**thread signal handler:**

- `void * thread_signal_handler(void * arg)`

> void * thread_signal_handler(void * arg) {
>
> ```
>  sigset_t set;
>
>  int sig, n;
>
>  int * socket = (int*) arg;
>
>  sigemptyset(&set);
>
>  sigaddset(&set, SIGINT);
>
>  sigaddset(&set,SIGTERM);
>
>  while (server_UP) 
>  {
>    /* wait for a signal */
>    if (sigwait(&set, &sig))   
>       perror("Sigwait");
>   
>    /* received SIGINT or SIGTERM - closing server */
>    if ((sig == SIGINT || sig == SIGTERM))     {     
>       printf(TERM_SERVER"\n");
>
>    server_UP = 0; /* global variable */
>
>    /* close socket blocked on MAIN */
>
>    shutdown( *socket, SHUT_RDWR );
>  }
>   
>  return (void *) EXIT_SUCCESS;
> ```
>
> }

In this way, the signal is catched well and the server is terminated immediately.
I need, if there are matches in progress, to waiting that all the *workers* finish their jobs properly, so I want to know how to say to thread handler "did you receive a SIGINT (or SIGTERM)? Ok, waiting the termination of all workers".

Any suggests? If you need more code, i'll edit this post.

Comment: Call `pthread_join()` on all threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create them you can save all of the threads in an array or a list and at the end call pthread_join() on all of them.

```
while (pthread_list) {
    pthread_join(pthread_list->th_id, NULL);
    pthread_list = pthread_list->next;
}
```

If you don't want to keep track of all threads you can keep a count of running threads, increment it before calling pthread_create, decrement the count as each thread finishes.

Then in the handler you'll sleep for some seconds iteratively until the count becomes 0.

Comment: if u read the signature of this `pthread_join(tid[i], NULL)`, i exactly do this (i just use an array of pthread_t instead a list).

`while (i-- != 0)
    {
      pthread_join(tid[i], NULL); }`

Every time i created a thread, i put it in `tid[i]`

Is enough?

Comment: Yes it's enough. The pthread_join wait until the specified thread end so if you wait on all of them when you exit from the loop you're sure all threads'll are finished.

Comment: I'll put also a check in the main loop: if server_UP == 0 it should not accept any new connection. If you launch a thread after the  "join while" is started you may miss that thread. So you also have to put the while after the line server_UP = 0;

Comment: So like this?
`while (server_UP)
    {
       if(server_UP != 0) 
         { accept(...) ... }
    }`

Comment: I think that should be better something like: while(1) {accept(..); ... if (server_UP) {pthread_create(...)} else {break;} }. With your code even if you set server_UP to 0 the main thread is still waiting on the accept, so one thread may be created.